# Leaflet addMarkers icon not showing in R

Tags: r, leaflet

I'm attempting to add markers to a map, however for some reason the marker icon no longer renders:

[image: leaflet map of Boston showing missing marker image]

Here's a reproducible example shiny app:

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)
library(leaflet)



ui <- fluidPage(

    # Application title
    titlePanel("Leaflet example"),
    
    leafletOutput("example")

    
)

server <- function(input, output) {

    output$example <- renderLeaflet({
      leaflet() %>% 
        addProviderTiles(providers$Esri.WorldGrayCanvas) %>%
        setView(lng = -71.0589, lat = 42.3601, zoom = 15) %>%
        addMarkers(
          lng = -71.0589,
          lat = 42.3601
        )
      
    })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: When I run your example code, the marker shows up. Could you try updating your packages or restarting R?

Comment: Package update seems to have solved the issue; thanks for the tip.